# How to use router in Django REST not for viewsets, but for generic views?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a very basic question about DjangoREST and routering.

When I need to regist rest_framework.viewsets I am doing somethink like this (example from documentaton):

```
router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)
router.register(r'accounts', AccountViewSet)
```

But how to add to router views that are from rest_framework.generics package? Should I bild custom router (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#custom-routers)? What is the best practice?

Comment: Still urlpatterns are the best. Question has appeared in my mind by overthinking :P

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> But how to add to router views that are from rest_framework.generics package?

You don't. ViewSets adds a couple of compatibility layer to `rest_framework.generics` in order to work with routers.

> Should I bild custom router (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#custom-routers)? What is the best practice?

If you want to use a non viewset view, you'll be down to writing the regular Django url.

My feeling is the real question is quite different and would be something like, "how do I restrict viewset to some actions only".

In which case, the declaration of the `ModelViewSet` provides the answer:

```
class ViewSet(ViewSetMixin, views.APIView):
    """
    The base ViewSet class does not provide any actions by default.
    """
    pass


class GenericViewSet(ViewSetMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):
    """
    The GenericViewSet class does not provide any actions by default,
    but does include the base set of generic view behavior, such as
    the `get_object` and `get_queryset` methods.
    """
    pass


class ModelViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                   mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                   mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                   mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                   mixins.ListModelMixin,
                   GenericViewSet):
    """
    A viewset that provides default `create()`, `retrieve()`, `update()`,
    `partial_update()`, `destroy()` and `list()` actions.
    """
    pass
```

As you can see, you can specialize the `ModelViewSet` by selecting the required mixins and inheriting from `GenericViewSet`.

Comment: Unfortunately your answer assumes you're working with models which is not always the case. Just because you have a view that's not in a viewset, does not mean the view is utilizing a model to produce the rendered result.

Comment: Whether it uses models or not isn't relevant here. You can use ViewSets without models but routers only works with ViewSets.

Answer (score 1):

In case of generic views they don't use routers as they are class based views source-
[drf documentation for class-based views](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/#using-generic-class-based-views)