# django-rest-framework "AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_extra_actions' "

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

> django==3.2.4  djangorestframework==3.12.4

blog/serializer.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Blog

class BlogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = '__all__'
```

blog/views.py

```
from rest_framework import generics
from .models import Blog
from .serializers import BlogSerializer

class BlogListCreateView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Blog.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BlogSerializer

class BlogRetrieveUpdateDestroyView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Blog.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BlogSerializer
```

blog/urls.py

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'blogs', BlogListCreateView.as_view(), basename="blogs")
router.register(r'action/<int:pk>', BlogRetrieveUpdateDestroyView.as_view(), basename="action")

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

when i use router it shows **AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'**
but when i use normal django urls path it run successfully

blog/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('blog/', BlogListCreateView.as_view(), name="blog"),
    path('blog/<int:pk>', BlogRetrieveUpdateDestroyView.as_view(), name="action"),
]
```

Comment: Routers are used for _viewsets_ not for views...

Answer (score 1):

From documentation:

> Because we're using ViewSet classes rather than View classes, we
> actually don't need to design the URL conf ourselves. The conventions
> for wiring up resources into views and urls can be handled
> automatically, using a Router class.

So you don't need the path to be `'action/<int:pk>'`. `'action'` will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

[Routers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/) are used for `Viewsets`, not for `generics` views from Django. For Example:

```
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)
router.register(r'accounts', AccountViewSet)
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37661868/how-to-use-router-in-django-rest-not-for-viewsets-but-for-generic-views) how to do it using `generics`.